# Bind an Objective-C object to an existent Lua variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, lua

I have to bind an Objective-C object to a variable of a Lua script. I don't have write access to this Lua script, I just load and run it from the Objective-C code. I know it uses a variable, called `luaVar`, that uses methods defined in the object. Here is the Lua code:

```
function run()
    print("Running Lua script")
    print(luaVar)
    print("Ending Lua script")
end

run()
```

This script should print the `luaVar` variable, and not `nil`. Now, here is the Objective-C code I use. The function `validate` gets the Lua code in the `script` variable and the object to pass to Lua as `f` in the `theObject` variable:

```
#import "ScriptObject.h"

static const char* SCRIPT_OBJECT_LUA_KEY = "f";
ScriptObject* scriptObject = nil;

- (void)validate:(NSString*)script withObject:(ScriptObject*)theObject {

    L = luaL_newstate(); // create a new state structure for the interpreter
    luaL_openlibs(L); // load all the standard libraries into the interpreter
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    newScriptObject(L);

    // load the script
    int err = luaL_loadstring(L, [script cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    if (LUA_OK != err) {
        NSLog(@"Error while loading Lua script!");
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        return NO;
    }

    // call the script
    err = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
    if (LUA_OK != err) {
        NSLog(@"Error while running Lua script: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        return NO;
    }

    lua_close(L);
}


static int newScriptObject(lua_State *L) {
    ScriptObject * __strong *lgo = (ScriptObject * __strong *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(ScriptObject *));
    *lgo = scriptObject;

    luaL_getmetatable(L, SCRIPT_OBJECT_LUA_KEY);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_setuservalue(L, -2);

    NSLog(@"New ScriptObject created");
    return 1;
```

}

I tried the approach from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680055), but that didn't handle Objective-C objects. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056500/creating-lua-globals-in-objective-c-c-from-userdata), but it is not clear how it does the binding.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the object? What does "it uses methods defined in the object" mean?

Comment: @H2CO3 I want to call some of its methods. For example, if the Objective-C object has a `(NSString*)getString()` method, the Lua code may call `luaVar:getString()` and get the result.

Comment: You will have to clarify. Show the Lua code you would like to be able to write. Have you looked at https://github.com/torus/Lua-Objective-C-Bridge? You might be able to find solution by looking at how Wax bridged Lua and Objective-C (Wax is no longer maintained but that's beside the point, the techniques should still apply).

Comment: @Schollii I added the Lua code I want to write, just a simple function using a non-nil `luaVar` variable. I already looked at what you proposed but `Lua-Objective-C-Bridge` is not iOS-oriented and `Wax` is just extremely difficult to port to a modern iOS project. In fact, I needed something simpler that a full solution such as those. I found the answer anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. It was just a missing line at the end of the `newScriptObject` function which sets the defined variable as a Lua global:

```
lua_setglobal(L, SCRIPT_OBJECT_LUA_KEY);
```